# Disable/Enable custom property of a custom component in Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I've created a custom component with custom properties which I later import in the Scene Builder.

I'd like to have the option to disable one or more of those properties based on the value of another, how can I do that?

**CustomControl:**

```
public class CustomControl extends TextField {

    private BooleanProperty active = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private ObjectProperty<TypesEnum> selectType = new SimpleObjectProperty<TypesEnum>();
    
    public CustomControl() {
        super();
        getStyleClass().add("custom-control");
        
        active.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                
                if (newValue) {
                    
                    // Enable 'selectType'
                }
                else {
                    
                    // Disable 'selectType'
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active.get();
    }
    
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active.set(active);
    }

    public BooleanProperty activeProperty() {
        return active;
    }
    
    public TypesEnum getSelectType() {
        return selectType.get();
    }

    public void setSelectType(TypesEnum selectType) {
        this.selectType.set(selectType);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<TypesEnum> selectTypeProperty() {
        return selectType;
    }
}
```

**TypesEnum:**

```
public enum TypesEnum {

    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B,
    TYPE_C
}
```

In the image below you can see an example of some disabled properties in Scene Builder (default `HBox`, with default `Layout` properties).

[image: HBox_Layout_Extra_Properties]

So when my `active` and `selectType` properties are shown in Scene Builder, when I click on `active`, I'd like `selectType` to become disable like in the image above.

[image: Custom Properties]

Comment: use a StyleableProperty

Comment: @kleopatra I've edited my answer to better reflect what I'm looking for (I guess I should've avoided naming my variables `color`, `selectColor` and `ColorsEnum`). From what I understand from [this explanation (page 24)](https://riptutorial.com/Download/javafx.pdf), `StyleableProperty` is used for when you want to change a custom `CSS` property of a custom control or just a `CSS` property of said custom control, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: ahh .. misunderstood your question ;)

Comment: `SceneBuilder` does not provide such a feature as far as I know. You can make it to show a disabled `ComboBox` with the use of a `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<TypesEnum>` but then you cant swap it to be an `ObjectProperty<TypesEnum>`, so that it would be shown as a not disabled `ComboBox`.

Comment: @anko That's truly unfortunate. I guess I'll have to approach my situation in a different way. Thank you for the information, mate.